# a4j:commandLink only calling action method on the second time it is clicked

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a `<rich:dataTable>` that contains `<a4j:commandLink>`.

I've added an `<a4j:jsFunction>` to the same form, which is placed inside an `<a4j:region>` with `renderRegionOnly="true"`.

The problem is that if I have this `renderRegionOnly="true"` the commandLinks inside the table will only launch the action binded method the second time they are clicked! Has anyone ever faced a similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This happened once to me because there was an `<a4j:support>` (RF 3.x) or `<a4j:ajax>` (RF 4.x) tag component that triggered on a specific event in a component, in my case was the onblur event in an `<h:inputText>`, make sure you don't have a similar situation. Also, it would be good to add JSF and RF version you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to correct the problem so i used the workaround of having a hidden field instead of calling that jsFunction when the page first loads.
Thanks for the tip.